# How to get a specific Item from a ListView by clicking on it?

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

First of all, I'm a beginner in android programming. So dont be too harsh :P

Anyway, I have a recycling ListView, containing an Image and a Text per List Item.
Let's say there are 100 different Items. Every Item clicked leads me to my Activity "DetailActivity.class" with the "detail_layout.xml". Now I want to configurate this layout depending on which Item was clicked.

TestActivity.java:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i <= 99; i++) {
    list.add(detail_array[i]); 
    //detail_array[] contains Strings which are used to add Items to the list.
}
private ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
myList.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(TestActivity.this,list));
```

MyCustomAdapter.java:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<String> mListItemsTV;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder.itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_view);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }
    String stringItem = mListItemsTV.get(position);
    if (stringItem != null) {
        if (holder.itemName != null) {
            holder.itemName.setText(stringItem);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_image_view);
            if(holder.itemName.getText() == "SomeName") {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.somedrawable);
            }
    return view;
}
```

To be honest, I've got those from some kind of tutorial and I guess I know whats happening there^^
Now, how can I manage to get which Item was clicked? I tried it several times with "setOnClickListener" but it never seems to work. How do I use this? Should I use this? Where do I have to use it?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is listview is generally dynamic so you will have a collection of an arbatrary number of items that you want to register with a listener. Oclicklistener will not work unless you register each item separate (not a good idea). Use onitemclicklistener to register the collection this link should help. http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1351248&q=handling-android-listview-onitemclick-event

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use setOnItemClickListener. This is an example on how it's used. You'll need to adapt it to your code. But you can see how you would reference an individual item in the list.

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

```
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
      int position, long id) {
    final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0)
        .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            list.remove(item);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            view.setAlpha(1);
          }
        });
  }

});
```

}

I'll fix the formatting when I get home. On mobile ATM. If anyone wants to edit the code feel free.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an adapter then try this:

```
   @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    switch(position){
    /*
     * The case is the list position
     */
    case 0:

        break;
    case 1:

        break;
    }

}
```